# spring security 3 configuration with existing project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

**Exception**

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1094)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:217)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:145)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:179)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</display-name>

<filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


 <listener>
 <listener-  class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener- class>
 </listener>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
     </param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: help me i have added the jar also and thanks in advance

Comment: You habe a broken reference in your `baens.xml`. Share your config.

Comment: Please update your question with your web.xml and spring security config file. Most probable you haven't loaded your spring configuration or you have defined the bean with a different name rather than `springSecurityFilterChain`

Comment: i have loaded the springSecurityFilterChain ,inspite of its showing the exception

Comment: Is your `web.xml` valid? I see `<listener-  class>`...